# Regex to match beginning and end of a word with a vowel

Tags: regex

I'm trying with the following `Regex`:

```
/^[aeiou]\..*[aeiou]$/
```

But it's not working, I tested "abcda" and didn't match.

Answer (score 61):

It should be just:

```
/^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$/
```

The extra `\.` you had would require the second character to be a literal dot, like in: "a.hello". But since your test case "abcda" does not include such a dot, it did not match.

Note that if you want to match upper case vowels as well, you could add the `i` modifier, as follows:

```
/^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$/i
```

If your intention is to only match strings where the ending vowel *is the same as* the vowel at the start, then use a back-reference `\1` like this:

```
/^([aeiou]).*\1$/i
```

Answer (score 14):

Regex for word start and end with vowel.

```
^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$
```

Regex for word start and end with same vowel.

```
^[a].*[a]$|^[e].*[e]$|^[i].*[i]$|^[o].*[o]$|^[u].*[u]$
```

Answer (score 14):

```
/^(a|e|i|o|u).*\1$/
```

This works for me.

Explanation:

When you put `^` character, then you indicate that you are verifying the string for the start. The parentheses are group separators.

So, when putting `(a|b|c)` you are telling that the first group to be tested will match with `a`, `b`, or `c`. In the example, it marks as group `(a|e|i|o|u)`. That means the string must start with any of those characters.

The `|` character acts as a boolean OR comparator.

The `.` indicates that any character except new line will be evaluated.

The `*` indicates that we are expecting 0 or more characters that match.

The `\1` acts as a reference from the result of the first group, in this case `(a|e|i|o|u)`.

The `$` character indicates the end of the string or the end of the line if we decide to go with multiline flag (`/m`).

Comment: Please add an explanation why and how this solution works.

Comment: It will check whether word starting and ending with vowels or not if it is, then only it will pass or else it will not

Comment: Well, that "explanation" is not what I had in mind. However, you should add the explanation to the answer by editing the answer. "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please provide a complete explanation one of like what is use of \1,

Comment: Well it is Correct Answer.
for example in JavaScript you can use it like
`const re = RegExp(/^(a|e|i|o|u).*\1$/)`
@La

Answer (score 10):

## Words beginning and ending with vowels

```
\b[aeiou](\w*[aeiou])?\b
```

`\b` stands for *word boundary* (in this case, beginning **and** ending of word). The optional grouping `()?` is there to match single vowel words (very important for languages like portuguese with words like `o`, `a` and `e` or even the english word `I`.).

## Words beginning **and** ending with the *same* vowel

```
\b(?<vowel>[aeiou])(\w*\k<vowel>)?\b
```

Don't try to replace `<vowel>` for some value. It´s there just for capturing the matched vowel.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this.

```
var re = /^([a,e,i,o,u]).*\1$/;
```

*\1 backreference and $ is used for the end.

Answer (score 4):

Actually none of the existing answers was covering the corner case of having single vowel.

### Begins and ends with any vowel:

```
/^[aeiou]$|^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$/
```

Breakdown explanation:

- `^[aeiou]$`

  - `^` - start of a string
  - `[aeiou]` - exactly one vowel.
  - `$` - end of a string.
- `|` - OR:
- `^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$`

  - `^` - start of a string
  - `[aeiou]` - exactly one vowel.
  - `.*` any - zero or more
  - `[aeiou]` - exactly one vowel
  - `$` - end of a string.

### Begins and ends with one and the same vowel

e.g match `aba`, but **not** match `abe`. We can backtrack to the first vowel:

```
/^[aeiou]$|^([aeiou]).*\1$/
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this regex suits you best:

```
/^a.*a$|^e.*e$|^i.*i$|^o.*o$|^u.*u$/
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression for words beginning and ending with the same vowel is:

```
var re = /(\ba(\w+)a\b|\be(\w+)e\b|\bi(\w+)i\b|\bo(\w+)o\b|\bu(\w+)u\b)/g;
```

While the regular expression for words beginning and ending with the any vowel is:

```
var re = /\b[aeiou]\w+[aeiou]\b/gi;
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can just write like this :-

`/^([aeiou]).+\1$/;`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
/^([aeiou]).+\1$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay if someone is looking for regex "end and start with same vowel"
this is the code.

```
/^([a|e|i|o|u]).*\1$/
```

[Demo](https://regexr.com/5uccp)

Comment: Why do you copy/paste [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047449/372239)?

Comment: oh, that did not come up in my search, this thread came and the answer did not work for me so I created mine and thought would be nice to share here. but now since mentioned it, should I delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

`let endsWithVowel = function(str) { let regex = /.*[aeiouAEIOU]$/ return regex.test(str) }`

```js
let endsWithVowel = function(str) {
let regex = /.*[aeiouAEIOU]$/
return regex.test(str)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `/[aeiou]+[a-z]+[aeiou]+/i`

Comment: Why is the `+` necessary after the first and last class? The OP just wants one vowel.

Comment: + means that you need one or more character to make a string. You can also specify how many character you want.

Comment: You are right about what `+` means. You have 3 classes first all the vowels `[aeiou]` then all alphabet `[a-z]` then again all vowels. I understand why you put a `+` after the middle class to get all the middle characters. I don't understand why the first and last class needs the `+`?

Comment: In first and last class the + means that the string should start with a vowel and must end with a vowel

Comment: `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy). If you only looking for 1 vowel `+` is not necessary.

Comment: This also matches inputs that do not necessarily start or end with vowels, as this pattern will just look for the first vowel before matching with the rest of it.